# Is any quality lost when saving a flat RGB PSD as PNG?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, file-format, color-profile, color-spaces

Sometimes when I have a PSD I'm working on, and I flatten it and do an incremental save, I save as PNG instead of PSD because **(1)** the file can be opened even without Photoshop on another machine, **(2)** it is obvious that it's flat from the file extension alone, and **(3)** PNG will result in a much smaller file size.

What I would like to know is, **am I losing any image quality by doing this?** I am wondering about color data, or possibly other data I haven't considered.

Considerations & details worth mentioning:

- Let's assume saving in the same bit depth, 8-bit PSD to 8-bit PNG, or 16-bit PSD to 16-bit PNG. (32-bit PSD to PNG doesn't work through the Save As menu, and using Export produces an 8-bit PNG)
- I am aware that guides are lost once the PNG is closed and re-opened.
- I am also aware that CMYK color space is unsupported in PNG, so this question only applies to RGB PSD files.
- I realize paths won't be saved in a PNG file.
- I realize additional channels (from saved selections, etc) won't be saved in a PNG file.
- Let's assume saving with the "Large file size" setting in PNG Format Options. (Other settings have caused problems when trying to re-edit later)

Thanks.

Comment: PNG24 and above are a lossless file formats, so no image quality is lost.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy All PNG files are lossless. Anyway, I think I found the answer I was looking for here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/105668/21178 In short: be careful with your color profiles.

Comment: Technically I guess, but will you use PNG8 on a 8bit image? You'll loose colors ergo the quality. As for the color profiles: png can embed them: if you work in something that's not sRGB you can always embed it.

Comment: @Mentalist  PNG8 is not 8 bits per channel, unlike an 8 bit per channel PSD. It's 8 bits in total, i.e indexed colour, like a GIF, 256 colours maximum. So if you use that format, you will definitely get colour loss.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you for that info! Sounds like it would make a good answer, if you would be willing to explain the difference between 8 bits per channel vs 8 bits total in a little more detail.

Comment: @Mentalist - I answered as a comment because it really doesn't address your question directly, I was simply making the point that PNG8 in Photoshop is indexed colour. Perhaps it would be better to ask about this as a specific question.  There are users here who could give low-down on the technicalities involved much better than me.

Comment: @BillyKerr I understand what you mean. In that case, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. (To the community: I welcome a more in-depth answer from whoever feels they can explain.)

Comment: I think your portability issue is untrue. PsD support is pretty wide due to the documentation of the format. You lose special features but nothing you woyldnt lose in a png. Personally losing all layers is the same as losing all work so png no good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to make it more clear: PNG format supports a lot of different combinations of channels: if you want, you can read more in depths in the [format description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Pixel_format).

*Generally* people care about two types: PNG8 (8bit per pixel, 256 colors) and PNG24 (24bit bit per pixel, Truecolor). Note that when you have a document in Photoshop that says `8bit`, it's 8bit per channel, not in total (so it's actually a 24b image), you can read more about color depth and how the number of colors is calculated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth#Direct_color).

PNG images also can include transparency:

- for PNG8 Photoshop only can have a 1bit transparency (so a pixel is
  transparent or not transparent) but there're [other utilities](https://pngquant.org/)
  that can save PNG8 with 8bit alpha transparency
- for PNG24 Photoshop can save full color image and full alpha transparency (technically it's a PNG32 now: 24b for color and 8b for transparency, but Photoshop just calls it *PNG24 with transparency*)

So to answer your question,

- if you save 8-bit documents with PNG24 you won't lose any data — no matter if your document has transparency or not;
- if you're saving an 8-bit document with PNG8, you'll lose colors (16mil colors will become 256)
- if you're saving an indexed color document (that has 256 colors at most — re-saving an existing `.gif` or indexed `.png` file for example), saving a PNG8 won't lose any data;

And several examples. The black images in the bottom row are the results of png images being put in Difference blending mode against the original psd: black means no pixels changed: png24 is completely black, png8 has a lot of non-black pixels due to color loss. Also note how PNG8 from Photoshop didn't preserve alpha gradient and PNG made by pngquant preserved it while compressing the image:

[image]

Comment: For those who might come along and see quality problems: those are jpeg artifacts from the saving of the screenshot for posting, not a result of the PNG comparisons as described.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! So if I understand correctly, "PNG-8" and "8 Bits/Channel" are different. After opening a PNG saved with Ps, when I go to Image > Mode it shows "8 Bits/Channel" and and there is gradation in the alpha channel (so it must be PNG-24), but if I Save For Web & Devices and select "PNG-8" I can see that the transparency is crushed to 1-bit. Is this an accurate description?

Comment: If you open a PNG8, mode will show `Indexed color`: you can't have layers and more than 256 colors in this mode. `8 Bits/Channel` will be for a file saved with PNG24. But otherwise yes.